# how to change compiled ipa file icons and name of application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, icons

We can do this for android using apk file manager or just renaming it to zip file and changing the zip file.

But How to do it for IOS file?
I heard apple store allows us to change it but again we are targetting ad-hoc as well. How to do that...?

actually we have created 100 iOS ipa and android apk files for many clients and we want them to change there icons & name of application by themselves.
Each apk and ipa is assigned an ID which retrieves the data from internet upon installation and works accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can't with iOS.

You must change the name and icon in your project again and have to create new IPA files.

Comment: Thanks Ramshad. we can change icon on appstore right...?! can on appstore we can change name of the application to?

Comment: thanks again for such a quick reply I have marked it as answer. You mean we can change icons and name while submitting to appstore...M I RIGHT??

Comment: As per below help we can only change Large icon for the binary...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 0):

[As Per apple documentation of itunes connect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)  we can only change **large icon** for the application which is ratina icon and is 1024*1024 px size. I guess we can **NOT** change the name of app and icon while submitting to itunes store